# What are viable options for data synchronization and transformation in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-synchronization

**Our company needs to synchronize two sql server 2008 databases on two different servers.**

1. The database schemas are about 50% different so transformation is needed.
2. Synchronization needs to be done in real time.
3. Synchronization needs to be bi-directional.

**What are some good practices used for this purpose?**

**We have analyzed the following solutions and they didn't work for us**

**Microsoft Sync Framework**. This option doesn't work because of the amount of time required to set up the framework (specifically the metadata tables/triggers/sprocs that the framework uses). It is also a newer framework so documentation/examples are scarce and the product might not be as stable as some other solutions.

**SQL Server Integration Services**. This solution has a learning curve and possible road blocks. It also seems to be too much for just this purpose.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Replication.

Create views in both databases to emulate the 50% of the other side that is different.  These, along with the tables that still match will server as your publication source.  For the tables that match, just set up two-way replication.

For the tables that do not match use the emulations views as the publication sources.  Add a "SourceID" to their base tables to identify what server they were originally created on, and then setup replication filters to insure that no server ever receives a row that it originally created.  Publish these views to the other server(s) one-way only.  You may need to make these  as indexed views in order for it to work (sorry, I can't remember).

Comment: This approach will actually work for us and the set up is very simple. Thank you.